# conformal map from croissant to disk

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem from a test that I took few hours ago - and the test was finished just before.

Let $U = \{|z-4i|<4\}\cap \{|z-i|>1\}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (which looks like a croissant). Describe a (surjective) conformal map from $U$ to a unit disk $D = \{|z|>1\}$.

Since both sets are simply connected, such map exists by a Riemann mapping theorem. However, I can' find any explicit such map. As I know, there are two inequivalent definitions of a conformal map:

1) $f:U\to V$ is a conformal map if it is biholomorphic.

2) $f:U\to V$ is a conformal map if $f$ is holomorphic and $f'$ vanishes nowhere.

Since two sets are biholomorphic, such map satisfies both definition. I want to know an explicit map between to sets that is biholomorphic, and if it is hard to describe, I want to know a map that is conformal in the sense that satisfies the second definition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the inequalities defining the region correct?  It looks to me like the first set is a subset of the second set.

Comment: It might be a typo but isn't $\{ |z - 4i | < 4 \} \cap \{ |z+i| > 1 \} = \{ |z - 4i| < 4 \}$? pheraps it is $z+4i$ or $z-i$

Comment: Anyway at a abstract level, sending the center of the small circle to $\infty$ leaves you with a strip that can be sent to a halfplane using $e^z$ together with the right rototraslation. From there sending this to righthalf plane involves maybe another rototraslation and eventually you can use the well known map $\frac{z+1}{1-z}$ (correct me if wrong) to send this into the circle

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry it is $z-i$, thanks!

Comment: *Now* it looks like a croissant.

Comment: @JayTuma Could you elaborate more? I can't understand how $U$ can be mapped to a strip.

Comment: The map $z\mapsto 1/z$ will send the two circles to two parallel lines.  Then you can follow the procedure outlined by JayTuna.  (I didn't understand the first step in his comment.)

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! I would just write down the procedure for others.

Comment: Sorry for me being too informal ^^" i was in a hurry. Anyway that's exaclty what i meant

Answer (score 1):

By following JayTuma and saulspatz's comments, I'll write down the solution for others.

First, send the croissant to a strip by the map $z\mapsto 1/z$. This sends the big circle to the line $\Im z = 1/4$, and the small circle to the line $\Im z = 1/2$. Now map this strip by $z\mapsto z-i/4$ so that one of the boundary lines became $x$-axis and the other one became $\Im z = 1/4$. 
Now by the map $z\mapsto e^{4\pi z}$, it maps to a upper half plane $\Im z>0$, since $e^{4\pi(x+iy)} = e^{4\pi x}(\cos 4\pi y + i \sin 4\pi y)$. Finally, a usual map $z\mapsto i(1-z)(z+1)$ maps the upper half plane to the unit disk. By composing all of these maps, we get a conformal map $f:U\to \mathbb{D}$ where 
$$
f(z) = \frac{i(1+e^{4\pi/z})}{1-e^{4\pi/z}}. 
$$